# Django models.DateTimeField, how to store the value without seconds?

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have this model

```py
class Appointments(models.Model):

    options = (
        ('waiting', 'In Attesa'),
        ('confirmed', 'Confermato'),
        ('closed', 'Chiuso'),
    )

    duration = (
        ('15', '15 minuti'),
        ('20', '20 minuti'),
        ('30', '30 minuti'),
        ('40', '40 minuti'),
    )

    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    patient_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    patient_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    patient_email = models.EmailField(_('email address'))
    patient_phone = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default='waiting')
    message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True) 
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    appointment_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=duration, default='15')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date', )
        unique_together = ('appointment_date', 'room', )
```

How can I store `appointment_date` value without seconds in the DB?
Right now the value is like this `2021-11-05 17:30:43`
I'd like to store it as `2021-11-05 17:30`

That's because otherwise `unique_together` is basically useless for what I need.

Comment: related: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/pattern/date-time-field-s-that-store-a-week-or-month.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote [an article](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/pattern/date-time-field-s-that-store-a-week-or-month.html) about constructing variants of a `DateTimeField` that will truncate to a week, month, minute, etc.

In this case we can make a `MinuteDateTimeField` with:

```
# app_name/fields.py

from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import DateTimeField

class DateTruncMixin:

    def truncate_date(self, dt):
        return dt

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super().to_python(value)
        if value is not None:
            return self.truncate_date(value)
        return value

class MinuteDateTimeField(DateTruncMixin, DateTimeField):
    
    def truncate_date(self, dt):
        return dt.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Then you can use this `MinuteDateTimeField` with:

```
# app_name/models.py

from app_name.fields import MinuteDateTimeField

class Appointments(models.Model):
    # ⋮
    appointment_date = MinuteDateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Great explanation, thank you very much, it worked like a charm!